# Connect to AWS MSK Kafka cluster from azure service, Private key check failed. no certificate assigned

Tags: apache-kafka, mtls, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am trying to connect to an AWS MSK cluster from an Azure Service. We are using confluent kafka dotnet libraries in the code and also mTLS for the connection as below.

```
var consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig
                {
                    GroupId = kafkaConsumerConfiguration.ConsumerConfig.GroupId,
                    BootstrapServers = kafkaConsumerConfiguration.ConsumerConfig.BootstrapServers,
                    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
                    EnableAutoCommit = true,
                    EnableAutoOffsetStore = false,
                    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.Ssl,
                    EnableSslCertificateVerification = true,
                    SslCaCertificateStores = "Root,CA,Trust",
                    SslCertificatePem = kafkaConsumerConfiguration.ConsumerConfig.ConsumerPublicCert,
                    SslKeyPem = kafkaConsumerConfiguration.ConsumerConfig.ConsumerPrivateCert,
                    SslKeyPassword = kafkaConsumerConfiguration.ConsumerConfig.PrivateCertPassword
                };
```

As shown, I am providing the client's public and private certificates and also the private certificate password.

But we get the following error when trying to connect.

```
Private key check failed: error:140A80B1:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_check_private_key:no certificate assigned
```

Any idea how to figure out what is wrong?